# Android Studio 3.0 compile time error

Tags: android, gradle, java-8, android-studio-3.0

After upgraded Android Studio `2.3.1` to `3.0 Canary2`, my project cannot run properly.I already read [Migrating Doc](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/05/android-studio-30-canary-1-sdk-updates.html).First it shows Gradle Build Success, and then it shows many error compile time.Here is my Gradle files and error output.Any helps will be appreciated.

Project 's Gradle File

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha2'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.22.1'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.6'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App 's Gradle File

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 16
        versionName "2.0.0.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    //Support Library
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    //Network Call
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    //Image Loading
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    //Animation
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
    //Material Progressbar
    compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.1.6'
    //Bottom Navigation
    compile 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:1.3.3'
    //Discrete SeekBar for TOC fast scroll
    compile 'org.adw.library:discrete-seekbar:1.0.1'
    //Chip Cloud for Tag
    //Tag Group
    compile 'com.github.fiskurgit:ChipCloud:2.1.0'
    //Easy Permissions for Android M
    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.1.9'
    //Date Time Picker
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.5.0'
    //Shortcut Badger
    compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.10@aar'
    //Expandable RecyclerView for Review
    compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:3.0.0-RC1'
    //Testing
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4'
    compile 'me.gujun.android.taggroup:library:1.4@aar'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    Test Lib
    debugCompile 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.0'
    compile 'net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:1.3.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2') {
        // Necessary to avoid version conflicts
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
    //Crashylitics
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
}
```

Error Output after Gradle Build Success,

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: signature-polymorphic method called without --min-sdk-version >= 26
Error:com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: signature-polymorphic method called without --min-sdk-version >= 26
Error:  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
Error:  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
Error:  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
Error:  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)
Error:  at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:146)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilder.processOutputs(DexArchiveBuilder.java:110)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilder.convert(DexArchiveBuilder.java:91)
Error:  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransformCallable.lambda$cacheMissAction$0(DexArchiveBuilderTransformCallable.java:236)
Error:  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransformCallable$$Lambda$391/941987661.run(Unknown Source)
Error:  at com.android.builder.utils.FileCache.lambda$createFile$1(FileCache.java:260)
Error:  at com.android.builder.utils.FileCache$$Lambda$393/346077510.call(Unknown Source)
Error:  at com.android.builder.utils.FileCache.lambda$null$5(FileCache.java:443)
Error:  at com.android.builder.utils.FileCache$$Lambda$398/352869820.accept(Unknown Source)
Error:  at com.android.builder.utils.SynchronizedFile.doActionWithSingleProcessLocking(SynchronizedFile.java:291)
Error:  at com.android.builder.utils.SynchronizedFile.write(SynchronizedFile.java:234)
Error:  at com.android.builder.utils.FileCache.lambda$queryCacheEntry$6(FileCache.java:415)
Error:  at com.android.builder.utils.FileCache$$Lambda$394/908370962.accept(Unknown Source)
Error:  at com.android.builder.utils.SynchronizedFile.doActionWithSingleProcessLocking(SynchronizedFile.java:291)
Error:  at com.android.builder.utils.SynchronizedFile.read(SynchronizedFile.java:217)
Error:  at com.android.builder.utils.FileCache.queryCacheEntry(FileCache.java:391)
Error:  at com.android.builder.utils.FileCache.createFile(FileCache.java:273)
Error:  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransformCallable.getFromCacheAndCreateIfMissing(DexArchiveBuilderTransformCallable.java:185)
Error:  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransformCallable.call(DexArchiveBuilderTransformCallable.java:147)
Error:  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransformCallable.call(DexArchiveBuilderTransformCallable.java:53)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1689)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Error:Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: signature-polymorphic method called without --min-sdk-version >= 26
Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.code.Simulator$SimVisitor.visitConstant(Simulator.java:684)
Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.code.BytecodeArray.parseInstruction(BytecodeArray.java:764)
Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.code.Simulator.simulate(Simulator.java:101)
Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.processBlock(Ropper.java:790)
Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.doit(Ropper.java:745)
Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.convert(Ropper.java:350)
Error:  at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:285)
Error:  at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:141)
Error:  at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:95)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderCallable.translateClass(DexArchiveBuilderCallable.java:93)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderCallable.call(DexArchiveBuilderCallable.java:74)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderCallable.call(DexArchiveBuilderCallable.java:43)
Error:  ... 5 more
Error:...at bytecode offset 0000003b
Error:locals[0000]: [J
Error:locals[0001]: Ljava/lang/Object;
Error:locals[0002]: Ljava/lang/invoke/ConstantCallSite;
Error:locals[0003]: Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;
Error:locals[0004]: J
Error:locals[0005]: <invalid>
Error:locals[0006]: [J
Error:locals[0007]: I
Error:locals[0008]: I
Error:locals[0009]: J
Error:locals[000a]: <invalid>
Error:stack[0004]: Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;
Error:stack[0003]: <invalid>
Error:stack[0002]: J
Error:stack[0001]: <invalid>
Error:stack[top0]: J
Error:...while working on block 0034
Error:...while working on method reduceBy:([JLjava/lang/Object;)J
Error:...while processing reduceBy ([JLjava/lang/Object;)J
Error:...while processing org/boon/primitive/Lng.class
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.utils.FileCache$FileCreatorException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilder$DexBuilderException: Unable to convert input to dex archive.
Information:BUILD FAILED in 49s
```

Comment: Isn’t that exception message specific enough? The code only works with `min-sdk-version >= 26` and you have `minSdkVersion 19`. I’d suppose `targetSdkVersion 25` doesn’t play nicely with that constraint either…

Comment: I don't think, Android Studio 3.0 will not force to use Project min Sdk must be at least 26, and then, there is nothing for API 26, yet...right?

Comment: I don’t know anything about Android Studio, I’m just repeating what what the exception already said. I can tell you, that it looks like you are using lambda expressions and apparently that feature requires certain sdk support. If you think, the exception thrown by Android Studio is wrong about what Android Studio supports or requires, you’ll have to discuss that with Android Studio to convince it not to throw  that exception. Good luck.

Comment: `org.boon.primitive.Lng` uses classes from the `java.lang.invoke` package which is fully supported (I believe) only on Android O (= sdk 26).

Comment: Any solution for this issue?

Comment: After Android Studio 3.0 is out in Stable Channel, I try to test my project and built, it success in Stable Channel, but you will need to update Gradle Version to 4.1 and it will request to update Build Tool to use version 26